# Android: Can't Execute Handler.postDelayed inside a for / while loop without IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android

I want to change the background of an ImageView programatically, but inside a for / while loop on a separate thread. In my example, I have 3560 ImageViews in an ArrayList called 'lights'. I want to change each one's background inside a loop after a short delay, i.e. one changes every second.

```
ArrayList<ImageView> lights = new ArrayList<>();
int numberOfLights = 3560;
```

I originally used this code, but there is the problem that 'i' must be declared final as it is being called from an inner class, impossible if i need it for the for loop ...

```
Handler h = new Handler();

for( int i = 0; i < numberOfLights; i++) {

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lights.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_white);
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```

Therefore I tried using a **global** variable:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
counter = 0;

for( ; counter < numberOfLights; counter++) {

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lights.get(counter).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_white);
         }

    }, 1000);
}
```

It is as though this counter is completely ignored, h.postDelayed runs even when the counter is more than numberOfLights, I've tried just normal Threads with a Thread.sleep call, resulting in 'Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views' and also used the runOnUiThread method but having no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It was what the Exception says, you can't touch UI from another Thread. You should consider looking at AyncTask or use runOnUiThread() .

Comment: 3560 ImageViews... Terrible idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *for each* loop. It's way more elegant than the traditional loop and in this case you can make the local variable final

```
for(final ImageView light: lights) {

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            light.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_white);
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```

also, define handler as

```
Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

in order to run the code on UI thread

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new variable:

```
final int iCopy = i;
```

Then use that in your Runnable.

```
Handler h = new Handler();

for( int i = 0; i < numberOfLights; i++) {
    final int iCopy = i;

    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lights.get(iCopy).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.light_white);
        }

    }, 1000);
}
```

This however may not avoid the IndexOutOfBoundsException if `lights` is being modified in the mean time.  In that case a range check or making a copy of the array or light would solve your issue.